# Access ng-pattern in error message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have an ng-repeat for a list of attributes and want to show error messages for each input. For a pattern error I also want to show the specific regex it has to match.

Can I access an input's pattern somehow? I know I could add an attribute containing the regex but I would like to know if there is an angular way somehow.

(This is an oversimplified example, the regexes can be different for different attributes)

```
<form name="form">
    <div data-ng-repeat="(attributeName, attributeMetaData) in configuration.metaData">

        <input data-ng-model="configuration[attributeName]" type="text" name="{{attributeName}}" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/">

        <span data-ng-show="form[attributeName].$error.pattern && form[attributeName].$dirty">
            Please check your input format [pattern should go here]
        </span>   
    </div>
</form>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lisapfisterer/ndu2g0ev/

Comment: Do you want something like HH:MM to show up or the actual regex pattern that you have set in `data-mg-pattern` ?

Comment: The regex pattern would be fine. It's for a rather technical audience and should stay highly generic.

Comment: In that case, aren't you better off storing that pattern in a scope variable and displaying it in the error message? `$scope.timeRegexPattern = '/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/'`

Comment: I thought about that. But I thought Angular might have a built-in solution. Like you can access the error state of a form input.

Comment: Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1tanx93y/) - is it OK? Or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/1tanx93y/1/).

Comment: Optionally, your regex pattern can be a part of a relevant model. Then you can just access it, like you normally would.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this demo only works with one regex. Then I could just insert it in the text. I have a complex model and many different regexes. I could do something like "Check your format {{patternList[attributeName]}}".

Comment: @lisap. I created this fiddle with my thoughts: http://jsfiddle.net/frishi/ja5n642c/1/

Comment: This solution works. But I can't change the model because I send this to the server and the database update doesn't work if I add additional values.

Comment: I don't know what db you are using, but you can selectively save model fields into, say mongo. If this does not apply to your case, then I guess your best bet is to have a model containing just regexes.

Comment: A separate model is what I'm using now. You can add this as an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your restriction that the model cannot be changed, I guess your best bet is to have a separate model containing just regexes